# What is the Type returned by GetValues in each of the overloaded versions

Tags: vb.net

```
Module Module1
    Enum Colors
        Red
        Green
        Blue
        Yellow
    End Enum
    Sub main()
        Dim values = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Colors)) ' Statement 1
        Console.WriteLine(values.GetType) 'O/P: Colors[]
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

`Values` expectedly is of type `Colors[]`. Now my question is which of the overloaded versions of GetValues is being executed here? To put this in context the basic GetValues method returns an `Array` type whereas the overloaded version returns `TEnum[]` type. Since `Values` is not of `Array` type and is of a specific enum array type (in this case `Colors[]`, I am inferring that statement 1 is calling the overloaded version of the GetValues method.

Adding the [MSDN GetValues page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-6.0) for quick reference.

My Questions:

1. Is the above understanding right?
2. If not can someone pls give an example where we are using the overloaded version of the GetValues method that returns the `TEnum[]` type?

Also, as I understand from an answer posted by @John that the GetValues method that returns `Array` type is pre-generics and is not being called in the statement `GetValues(GetType(Colors))`. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: What else can it return, if it's declared as Array?

Comment: I agree...have updated the question

Comment: I still don't get your question. `GetType(Colors)` returns `Type` that is passed to the `GetValues (enumType As Type) As Array`. The returned array is immediately enumerated in the `For Each`.

Comment: @GSerg I have tried to frame the question more clearly

Comment: To your final question, the version that takes a type argument **is** being called in the statement `GetValues(GetType(Colors))`.  The generic version is called if you use `GetValues(Of Colors)()` (since there isn't an argument, the generic type argument can't be inferred and must be provided explicitly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I just realised that the generic overload was only introduced in .NET 5, so any earlier versions can only use the non-generic version. That means .NET Core 3.1 or earlier and any version of .NET Framework. It is always a good idea to read the documentation and confirm exactly what .NET versions a type or method applies to.

ORIGINAL:

Either will work but the first was authored when generics didn't exist. Generic methods are generally better than non-generic ones. You can do this:

```vb
Dim values = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Colors))
```

or this:

```vb
Dim values = [Enum].GetValues(Of Colors)()
```

and, in the second one, the variable will be type `Colors()`, which is really what you want.

As for that `As Structure` generic constraint, it's there because that's as close as you can get to constraining `TEnum` to be an actual `Enum`. You can't actually constrain it that far but at least you can constrain it to be a structure, so no one can specify a class when calling that method. As `Enums` are structures under the hood, because they are all numeric types - `Integer` by default - under the hood. Someone could still specify a structure that isn't an `Enum` when calling that method, but the non-generic method would allow them to specify a class as well.

Comment: I believe  what you are saying is that `Dim values = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Colors))` returns the TEnum() type -->the `values.GetType` confirms the same as it returns `Colors[]`. So what is the second statement that you have written - `Dim values = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Colors))` ? How exactly to write this second statement in the editor?

Comment: Thanks for your post...have used your example to make the question more clear.

Comment: @Sougata, my apologies. I wrote that second statement using C# syntax by mistake. I have corrected it to use VB syntax. Basically, if you're targeting .NET framework 2.0 or later, which you are, use the generic method. The first method is basically obsolete since the introduction of generics, unless you specifically need to be able to use a `Type` object created at run time.

Comment: @Sougata, I have updated my answer with relevant information re version support.

Comment: @user18387401 thanks...your clarification helps. But where is the correction? I don't see anything has changed in the answer.

Comment: @Sougata, sorry, wrong account. Should be there now.

Comment: s/can/can't in the second sentence of your final paragraph, i.e. it should be "You **can't** actually constrain it that far..."